# How to add value into option using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here is my code for js

```
function addTag(tag) {
  var tags = document.getElementById("tags");
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent = tag.value;
  tag.value = "";
  span.setAttribute("onclick", "this.remove()");

  tags.append(span);
}

function addOption() {
  var x = document.getElementById("tag");
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.textContent = tags.textContent;
  x.add(option);
}
```

Once the user click on the **tags** it will close can should display the value to the option but, I only manage to create a blank space inside the option.

[Here is related JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8cen2muh/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `tags` `span` to contain all `option` `spans`.

Then made each `span` inside `tags` responsible to add itself back to `select` and remove itself from `tags` `span`.

Please see the changes in the code as per above logic.

```js
function addTag(tag) {
  var tags = document.getElementById("tags");
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent = tag.value;
  tag.value = ""; //clear the field when choose or pressed enter key
  span.style.backgroundColor = "#E5E6E7";
  span.style.margin = " 5px";
  span.style.padding = "5px";

  //span will add itself back to select and remove itself from tags
  span.setAttribute("onclick", "addOption(this)");

  if (span.textContent == "Fast Food") {
    $('option[value="Fast Food"]').remove();
  } else if (span.textContent == "Vegan") {
    $('option[value="Vegan"]').remove();
  } else {
    $('option[value="Food"]').remove();
  }
  tags.append(span);
}

function addOption(span) {
  var x = document.getElementById("tag");
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.textContent = span.textContent;
  x.add(option);
  span.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Food Type</label><br>
    <span id="tags"></span>

    <select id="tag" onchange="addTag(this)" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-All-</option>
      <option value="Fast Food">Fast Food</option>
      <option value="Vegan">Vegan</option>
      <option value="Food">Food</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, we can make use of the event system. This makes for cleaner code.

The main issue with your code is that you were trying to get `textContent` of `tags` which *doesn't exist as a variable. Instead it will reference the `id="tags"` element.

`textContent` only returns the text value of that element, not its children. In this case it is empty.

```js
// here we use jQuery's event system to define what happens
// for the events below    
$(document)
    .on("click", ".tag", function(){
        removeTag(this);
    })
    .on("change", "#tag", function(){
        addTag(this);
    });

function removeTag(tag){
    addOption(tag.textContent);
    tag.remove();
}

function addTag(tag) {
    var tags = document.getElementById("tags"),
        span = document.createElement("span");

    span.textContent = tag.value;

    tag.value = ""; //clear the field when choose or pressed enter key
    
    // could you add the following styles as a class?
    span.style.backgroundColor = "#E5E6E7";
    span.style.margin          = "5px";
    span.style.padding         = "5px";

    span.className = "tag";
    
    // no need to set `onclick` here as we're handling at the top of this code
    
    // we can use the text to find the element
    // instead of a repeating if else statment
    $('option[value="' + span.textContent + '"]').remove();

    tags.append(span);
}

function addOption(text) {
    var x      = document.getElementById("tag"),
        option = document.createElement("option");

    option.textContent = text;

    // we also need to set the value here
    // since we're looking for it in `addTag`
    option.value = text

    x.add(option);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Food Type</label><br>
    <span id="tags"></span>

    <select id="tag" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-All-</option>
      <option value="Fast Food">Fast Food</option>
      <option value="Vegan">Vegan</option>
      <option value="Food">Food</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ES6 and improvements**

```js
$(document)
    .on("click", ".tag", (event) => removeTag(event.currentTarget))
    .on("change", "#tag", (event) => addTag(event.currentTarget));

function removeTag(tag){
    addOption(tag.textContent);
    tag.remove();
}

function addTag(tag) {
    let tags = $("#tags"),
        span = $('<span class="tag" />');

    span.text(tag.value);

    tag.value = ""; //clear the field when choose or pressed enter key
    
    // we can use the text to find the element
    // instead of a repeating if else statment
    $(`option[value="${span[0].textContent}"]`).remove();

    tags.append(span);
}

function addOption(text) {
    let x      = $("#tag"),
        option = $('<option />');

    option
        .text(text)
        .val(text);

    x.append(option);
}
```

```css
.tag {
  background-color: #E5E6E7;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Food Type</label><br>
    <span id="tags"></span>

    <select id="tag" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-All-</option>
      <option value="Fast Food">Fast Food</option>
      <option value="Vegan">Vegan</option>
      <option value="Food">Food</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had made some logical mistakes,
You can update the fiddle as follows:

```js
function addTag(tag) {
  var tags = document.getElementById("tags");
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent = tag.value;
  span.setAttribute("onclick", "removeTag(this);");
  tag.options[tag.selectedIndex].remove();
  tags.append(span);
}

function removeTag(elm) {
    elm.remove();
  var x = document.getElementById("tag");
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.textContent = elm.textContent;
  x.add(option);
}
```

```css
#tags span{
  background-color: #E5E6E7;
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Food Type</label><br>
    <span id="tags"></span>

    <select id="tag" onchange="addTag(this)" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-All-</option>
      <option value="Fast Food">Fast Food</option>
      <option value="Vegan">Vegan</option>
      <option value="Food">Food</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```